# How to use TypeORM transactions?

Tags: typescript, transactions, nestjs, typeorm

I have a problem with transaction in TypeORM, below is an example code:

```
const someFunction = async () => {
    try {
        await this.entityManager.transaction(async (manager) => {
            //some operations on manager

           if (something) {
               throw new Error('error')
           }
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

can someone tell me why, when error in above `if` statement is throwing, then my whole NestJS app is crashed and I must restart this app? Maybe I bad try to stop transaction? How to properly manage transaction and trigger rollback?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I guess it depends on how you're calling `someFunction`. This function itself will work just fine as long as `transaction` from TypeORM bubbles up exceptions raised inside its callback (not sure if this the case tho)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the try/catch block, the transaction should catch unhandled errors

```
const someFunction = async () => {
  await this.entityManager.transaction(async (manager) => {
    //some operations on manager

    if (something) {
      throw new Error('error')
    }
  })
}
```